# Holder Inequality context

Tags: functional-analysis

I was trying to demonstrate that the space l^p is a metric space.

Let $p \geq 1$ a fixed real number. By definition, each element in the space $l^p$ is a sequence $x=(\xi_j)=(\xi_1,\xi_2,...)$ of numbers such that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|\xi_j|^p<\infty$$

define the metric by
$$d(x,y)=\left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\xi_i-\delta_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

where $x=(\xi_j)$ and $y=(\delta_j)$

Of course all axioms are trivial except the triangular inequality.

If I suppose that

$$\left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\xi_i+\delta_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\xi_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\delta_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

holds, this implies that the triangular inequality holds and the metric converges. So my goal is to prove that inequality. This is Minkowski inequality.

I'm not sure about that but, apparently, Minkowski proved this inequality in 1901. I do not know how he do it, I suppose that He used the Holder inequality, apparently Holder proved that in  1889, so its possibly that Minkowski was aware of the Hölder inequality. This makes the proof a lot of simple. What is the context? Why did Hölder arrive at this inequality? I want that information to construct that proof intuitively. Can someone tells me why Holder came up with that inequality? Thats the Holder inequality (I know how to proof that, but I don't have the intuition)

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\xi_i \delta_i| \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\xi_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\delta_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Comment: Interesting question. I think this question might be better suited for “History of maths and sciences” stackexchange, as it’s about the history of the Holder inequality. It isn’t completely off topic here though, so maybe wait for a second opinion before you close your question here.

Comment: Hölder was not the first to prove Holder's inequality.  It was Rogers (1888) [original paper](https://archive.org/stream/messengermathem01unkngoog#page/n183/mode/1up).  Holder gave a different proof, develop it more (and much better notation!) and so his name is attached.

Comment: I'm sorry, I agree with you. Is there a way for me to switch to the history session?

Comment: @user10354138 I searched for this article and couldn't find it. Thank you for the link. Do you know if I can find Holder's version?

Comment: Starting page 44:38 [here](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?GDZPPN00252421X).  Although it is in German you can see is much more accessible than Roger's.

Comment: Basically Roger's proof is playing with AM-GM to get Young's inequality and deduce Holder's inequality as a consequence but doesn't do much with it.  Holder's proof was with convexity, develop a basic version of Jensen's inequality.  Sometimes theorems are named after people who discovered it last because they do more with it.